# Iterating through columns on active_admin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to Ruby and Rails, so perhaps I'm not searching/asking this the right way. I'm using the ActiveAdmin gem and want to turn this:

```
column :purchase_price, :sortable => :purchase_price do |piece| 
  div :class => "price" do
    number_to_currency piece.purchase_price 
  end
end
column :appraised_value, :sortable => :appraised_value do |piece|
  div :class => "price" do
    number_to_currency piece.appraised_value
  end
end
column :sale_price, :sortable => :sale_price do |piece|
  div :class => "price" do
    number_to_currency piece.sale_price
  end
end
```

into this:

```
price_array = [:purchase_price, :appraised_value, :sale_price] 
price_array.each do |p|
  column p, :sortable => p do |piece|
    div :class => "price" do
      number_to_currency piece.p
    end
  end
end
```

...in the interest of DRY.

The longer solution works, but the shorter one gives a "NoMethodError in Admin::Pieces#index" and I'm kind of at a loss as to what's wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try changing piece.p to piece.send(p)

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to look into .send() for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As house9 said, my problem was that I tried calling `piece.p` when really it should be `piece.send(p)`. Still not exactly sure why you can't just replace all instances of `p` with the iterator loop like I did originally but maybe someone else can explain.

In any case, thank you!